# select multiple columns count one column and group by one column in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

I have a table named `[delivery]`, with columns `[ID],[Employee],[Post],[c_name],[Deli_Date],[note]`

I need to Select all columns and count `Employee` and then group by `Employee`.
data in the table like this:

```
  ---------------------------------------------------
  | Employee| Post      |c_name  |Deli_Date   |Note |
  |---------|-----------|---------------------|-----|
  |  DAVID  |MANAGER    | a      |11/11/2018  |note |
  |  DAVID  |MANAGER    | b      |01/01/2015  |note |
  |  SAM    |ACOUNTS    | c      |10/10/2016  |note |
  |  DAVID  |IT         | a      |10/02/2015  |note |
  |  DAVID  |DOCTOR     | c      |20/02/2017  |note |
  |  JAMES  |DELIVERYMAN| b      |05/05/2015  |note |
  |  OLIVER |DRIVER     | b      |02/02/2014  |note |
  |  SAM    |ACOUNTS    | c      |02/02/2012  |note |
```

this code:

```
select Employee, count(Employee) as TIMES from delivery
group by Employee
```

the result is: (but I need to show the other columns too).

```
| Employee| TIMES | 
|---------|-------|
|  DAVID  |   4   |
|  JAMES  |   1   |
|  OLIVER |   1   |
|  SAM    |   2   |
```

I need my code show Like This:

```
| Employee| TIMES | Post      |c_name  |Deli_Date   |Note |
|---------|-------|-----------|---------------------|-----|
|  DAVID  |   4   |MANAGER    | a      |11/11/2018  |note |
|  JAMES  |   1   |DELIVERYMAN| b      |05/05/2015  |note |
|  OLIVER |   1   |DRIVER     | b      |02/02/2014  |note |
|  SAM    |   2   |ACOUNTS    | c      |10/10/2016  |note |
```

what is the best Query could give me that result?

see columns `[c_name],[Deli_Date]` they shows the last inserted data.
or just give me the result without `[c_name],[Deli_Date]` it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the last date along with the count, you can use window functions:

```
select d.Employee, d.cnt, d.Post, d.c_name, d.Deli_Date, d.Note 
from (select d.*,
             count(*) over (partition by employee) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by employee order by deli_date desc) as seqnum
      from delivery d
     ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: thank you so much for your helping answer, it really gave the good one, but why there is another column named seqnum has 1 as value for all cells ?

Comment: @JohnYaram . . . Because the selection of the columns is not really important for showing the logic that you need.  So, I use `*`, which includes all columns from the subquery, event the extra ones that were added.

Comment: how to make it works on the TableAdapter on the dataset? because I am needed it on my c# app I posted the code in TapleAdapter Quey Builder get this error " The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported."

Answer (score 0):

You need to include all the non-aggregated columns in the select and group by clauses

```
select Employee,
  count(Employee) as TIMES,
  max(Deli_date) as LAST_DELI_DATE,
  post,
  note
from delivery
group by Employee, post, note
```

Max(Deli_date) will give you the latest date.

To get the latest c_name, note, post, etc. you will need a subquery with a rank function sorted by the deli_date. I will add the example later.

Comment: thank you so much for your helping answer, I will use your code for now and I will wait for your next answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Employee, count(Employee) as TIMES,Post,c_name,Deli_Date,Note from delivery
group by Employee
```

Comment: You have columns in the list after `SELECT`, that are not in the `GROUP BY` nor have an aggregation function applied to them. In most DBMS this isn't allowed. And in those it is allowed it mostly produces funny output.

Comment: Only query is just not make sense. provide explanation for your answer what you giving to OP.